# Adding a new column with sequential numbers that repeat over and over again

Tags: oracle, repeat, row-number, partition-by

How do we add a column to the results of the query below in order to assign...

```
Key_Week1 to the 1st record 
Key_Week2 to the 2nd record 
Key_Week3 to the 3rd record 
   
Key_Week1 to the 4th record 
Key_Week2 to the 5th record 
Key_Week3 to the 6th record
   
Key_Week1 to the 7th record 
Key_Week2 to the 8th record 
Key_Week3 to the 9th record

And on and on and on...following the above pattern repeatedly?

Alternatively, you can use 1, 2 and 3 instead of Key_Week1, 
Key_Week2 and Key_Week3 for the new columns values
```

```
select distinct trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day') as claim_eff_date, trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day') + 20 AS bwe_to_complete_by from
(
    select from_dt + (level - 1)/1 as GenerateTimeBy1Day 
    from (select from_dt
        ,to_dt
        ,to_dt - from_dt + 1 as days_between    
    from (select to_date('22-Dec-2019') as from_dt
               , to_date('30-Dec-2040') as to_dt 
          from dual))
    connect by (level - 1) <= days_between  
)
order by claim_eff_date
```

**Current Results:**
**(Simply run the above query. No sample data is needed)**

| Claim_Eff_Date | BWE_To_Complete_By |
| --- | --- |
| 22-DEC-19 | 11-JAN-20 |
| 29-DEC-19 | 18-JAN-20 |
| 05-JAN-20 | 25-JAN-20 |
| 12-JAN-20 | 01-FEB-20 |
| 19-JAN-20 | 08-FEB-20 |
| 26-JAN-20 | 15-FEB-20 |
| 02-FEB-20 | 22-FEB-20 |
| 09-FEB-20 | 29-FEB-20 |
| 16-FEB-20 | 07-MAR-20 |

**Desired Results:**

| Claim_Eff_Date | BWE_To_Complete_By | Key_Week_Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22-DEC-19 | 11-JAN-20 | Key_Week1 |
| 29-DEC-19 | 18-JAN-20 | Key_Week2 |
| 05-JAN-20 | 25-JAN-20 | Key_Week3 |
| 12-JAN-20 | 01-FEB-20 | Key_Week1 |
| 19-JAN-20 | 08-FEB-20 | Key_Week2 |
| 26-JAN-20 | 15-FEB-20 | Key_Week3 |
| 02-FEB-20 | 22-FEB-20 | Key_Week1 |
| 09-FEB-20 | 29-FEB-20 | Key_Week2 |
| 16-FEB-20 | 07-MAR-20 | Key_Week3 |

**OR**

| Claim_Eff_Date | BWE_To_Complete_By | Key_Week_Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22-DEC-19 | 11-JAN-20 | 1 |
| 29-DEC-19 | 18-JAN-20 | 2 |
| 05-JAN-20 | 25-JAN-20 | 3 |
| 12-JAN-20 | 01-FEB-20 | 1 |
| 19-JAN-20 | 08-FEB-20 | 2 |
| 26-JAN-20 | 15-FEB-20 | 3 |
| 02-FEB-20 | 22-FEB-20 | 1 |
| 09-FEB-20 | 29-FEB-20 | 2 |
| 16-FEB-20 | 07-MAR-20 | 3 |

And on and on and on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is just to calculate the `row_number()` and then do a `mod` to get the repitition.

```
with your_data as (
select distinct trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day') as claim_eff_date, 
                trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day') + 20 AS bwe_to_complete_by 
from
(
    select from_dt + (level - 1)/1 as GenerateTimeBy1Day 
    from (select from_dt
        ,to_dt
        ,to_dt - from_dt + 1 as days_between    
    from (select to_date('22-Dec-2019') as from_dt
               , to_date('30-Dec-2040') as to_dt 
          from dual))
    connect by (level - 1) <= days_between  
)
order by claim_eff_date
)
select your_data.*,
       mod( row_number() over (order by claim_eff_date) - 1, 3 ) + 1 key_week_group
  from your_data
```